# What is the workflow when including scripts in web pages with npm?

Tags: javascript, npm

There are many JS libraries and frameworks (e.g. jquery) that suggest doing this:

```
npm install foo
```

This gives you a `node_modules` directory in which there would be a `foo` directory. For most JS libraries that are meant for use in web pages, there will be a `dist` directory inside consisting of the required JS files that can be used.

I can now include JS with something like `<script src="/node_modules/foo/dist/foo.js">`, but I haven't found a single website doing that. Of course, this folder could be symlinked to something like `js` and then that could be used as `js/foo/dist/foo.js`, although I'm not sure if this is a good idea or whether it is even done in real life.

To me, copying scripts from online sources and putting them in my project repository seems like a better idea, although the advantages of automatic package management are lost in that case.

I do understand the workflow of npm when developing node.js-based server side applications, however, I'm having trouble understanding where the case involves scripts to be included in web pages. What exactly is the workflow in such cases?

Comment: I think most people would bundle the dependency, some will choose not to bundle it but those who do not bundle the dependency usually use a public CDN. That's not to say that fits your requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, do use NPM installed scripts in a web you have to use some bundler/builder which adds additional layer package management in your application. This would allow using modules like in server side. After bundling your modules into single or multiple chunks include these in your web like any other JavaScript files.

There are multiple tools for such job:

- http://browserify.org/
- https://webpack.github.io/
- http://rollupjs.org/

Answer (score 0):

Loading JavaScript in the browser is usually done through a module system, for which there are several competing standards (AMD, CommonJS) and implementations. One such implementation is Browserify, which assembles (at build time) the scripts you actually `require` into a single bundle.js file, which you can then easily include in HTML. (Other module systems work differently, for instance by loading each file separately when it is first needed).